# Run Multiple Custom Chef Error Handler's?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

Does anyone know if you can run lets say 2 error handlers in the same cookbook and have both of them run, one after another?  And if so how would you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlers are entirely independent of each other and you can run as many as you want. If you are using the `chef_handler` cookbook, use the titular resource multiple times.

Comment: How would you control the order of the handlers?

Comment: They run in the order they are declared, but chances are if you need a specific order it should be one handler running two methods.